# nodes.Current.SetValue("...") fluke?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpathnodeiterator

```
XPathNodeIterator nodes = nav.Select("//d:page/d:field/d:value", nsmgr);

...do stuff..

nodes.MoveNext();
nodes.Current.SetValue(i.ToString()); //<-HERE!
nodes.MoveNext();
nodes.Current.SetValue(numPages.ToString());

..do more stuff...
```

I use the `nodes.Current.SetValue()` function MANY times through this program, and it's only in this one instance (each time for this node) that it just doesn't want to work.  With breakpoints, it will show the that node's innerXML reflects `i` as it's supposed to.  Afterwards, printing it doesn't work.  I reselected that node in particular before saving the nav stream and still nothing.  (Actually, it isn't *nothing*.  It seems to be spaces or possibly even a line feed.  I have no idea why in this case it just doesn't work.  Below is the pertinant XML for these two nodes.

```
<field sid="PAGE">
      <itemlocation>
        <ae>
          <ae>absolute</ae>
          <ae>1051</ae>
          <ae>899</ae>
        </ae>
        <ae>
          <ae>extent</ae>
          <ae>47</ae>
          <ae>24</ae>
        </ae>
      </itemlocation>
      <value>
      </value>
      <borderwidth>0</borderwidth>
      <fontinfo>
        <ae>Times New Roman</ae>
        <ae>10</ae>
        <ae>plain</ae>
      </fontinfo>
      <justify>center</justify>
      <scrollhoriz>wordwrap</scrollhoriz>
      <scrollvert>fixed</scrollvert>
      <format>
        <ae>string</ae>
        <ae>optional</ae>
      </format>
      <next>OFPG</next>
      <previous>QTYFA_15</previous>
      <acclabel>asterisk.  when used as a.
hand receipt, enter hand receipt annex number.
hand receipt for quarters furniture, enter condition codes.
hand receipt annex or components receipt, enter accounting requirements code, ay r c.
enter page number.</acclabel>
    </field>
    <field sid="OFPG">
      <itemlocation>
        <ae>
          <ae>absolute</ae>
          <ae>1129</ae>
          <ae>899</ae>
        </ae>
        <ae>
          <ae>extent</ae>
          <ae>35</ae>
          <ae>24</ae>
        </ae>
      </itemlocation>
      <value>4</value>
      <borderwidth>0</borderwidth>
      <fontinfo>
        <ae>Times New Roman</ae>
        <ae>10</ae>
        <ae>plain</ae>
      </fontinfo>
      <justify>center</justify>
      <scrollhoriz>wordwrap</scrollhoriz>
      <scrollvert>fixed</scrollvert>
      <format>
        <ae>string</ae>
        <ae>optional</ae>
      </format>
      <previous>PAGE</previous>
      <next>NEXT_BUTTON</next>
      <acclabel>enter total number of pages.</acclabel>
    </field>
```

I am so confused why this isn't working... Anybody have any ideas?

EDIT:
More information:
I changed the XMLDocument to preserve whitespace.  This seems to fix it outputting spaces and/or a linefeed, but the value is still lost.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not working for both of the nodes you posted, or just one of them? (If so, which one is it working for, and which one not?)

Comment: It is not working for the first <value>.  It works fine for the second one, and hundreds of other <value>s in the document.  That is/was the output result before I started preserving the whitespace.  Now it's just empty....

Comment: Hmm, that is puzzling.  The only difference I see between the two nodes (and it probably doesn't matter) is the order of the 'Previous' and 'Next' child nodes.

Comment: Well. Glad I'm not the only one stumped by it. From the looks of it, 45 other people were also stumped.  Thanks for the input.  Next step is to try everything under the sun to get the value there.  Fortunately this is probably the least important field in the document I'm working with.  Still annoying....

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the value that is not being shoved into that one?